# URL common name matching - Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a domain with its common name. When I look at the certificate, I see the common name is `"*.example.com"`. Possible domains could be:

```
www.example.com  # A match the leftmost label of *.example.com
example.com  # A match the leftmost label of *.example.com
hello.example.com # A match for the leftmost label of *.example.com
foo.bar.example.com # Not a match for the leftmost label of 
*.*.* # Not a match for the leftmost label of *.example.com
www.*.com # Not a match for the leftmost label of *.example.com
```

*.example.com

I was trying to create the following regex:

```
import re
common_name = "*.example.com"
regex = common_name.replace('*','.*') + '$'
url = "foo.bar.example.com"
if re.match(regex, url):
   print "yes"
else:
   print "no"
```

What's wrong on my Regex?

Comment: you also need to escape (`re.escape()`) the string beforehand, because otherwise all the other `.` will be treated as regex wildcards

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
(?:^|\s)(\w+\.)?example\.com(?:$|\s)
```

it should match

- www.example.com
- hello.example.com
- example.com

based on your test string.

> Full solution:

```
import re

common_name = "*.example.com"
rxString = r'(?:^|\s)(\w+\.)?' + common_name.replace('.', '\.')[3:] + '(?:$|\s)'

regex = re.compile(rxString)
url = "foo.bar.example.com"

if regex.match(url):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

Input:

```
url                
-------------------
www.example.com    
example.com        
hello.example.com  
foo.bar.example.com
*.*.*              
www.*.com
```

Output:

```
url                  |  result
-------------------  |  -----------
www.example.com      |  yes
example.com          |  yes
hello.example.com    |  yes
foo.bar.example.com  |  no
*.*.*                |  no
www.*.com            |  no
```

Comment: It doesn't match `foo.bar.example.com`

Comment: @Felk: it's not supposed to match `foo.bar.example.com`. A wildcard certificate can only match a single level subdomain.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Please see what OP says: "foo.bar.example.com # Not a match for the leftmost label of "

Comment: Yep, sorry, I didn't quite get that. Nethertheless I think the desired solution was to not hardcode the `common_name` into a regexp, but rather generate one from it.

Comment: @Felk, good point. Please see updated solution. it's dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 3):

Using `re.search` with Regex pattern `'^[^.]*\.?example\.com$'`:

```
>>> import re
>>> def check_match(url):
...     if re.search(r'^[^.]*\.?example\.com$', url):
...         print url
... 
>>> 
>>> check_match('www.example.com')
www.example.com
>>> check_match('example.com')
example.com
>>> check_match('hello.example.com')
hello.example.com
>>> check_match('foo.bar.example.com')
>>> check_match('*.*.*')
>>> check_match('www.*.com')
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Exclude `.` character from your regexp and allow any other, also you have to add matching of `https://`, to do it replace line :

```
regex = common_name.replace('*','.*') + '$'
```

to

```
regex = r'(https?://)?' + common_name.replace('*.', r'([^\.]*\.)?') + '$'
```

**r'(https?://)?'** - would allow matching of `https://` and `http://` at the beginning of url

**r'([^.]*.)?'** - allow your domain to start from `*.`, excluding repeating of `.` ( domain `foo.bar.example.com` - would be considered as invalid)

Generally, all use cases provided in question would be matched correctly.

Comment: @philippe: where did the `https://` come from? That's not specified in your question. If it is a requirement you should add it to your question. Besides, you need to match the domain name; the scheme is not relevant.

Comment: @mhawke I will update the question. `http[s]` gets removed by urlparse so the domain is only `example.com` or `www.example.com`

Comment: @andriy  
Andriy, the common name *.example.com should match. Let's say "example.com" is valid, while "foo.bar.example.com" is not

Answer (score 3):

How about this (Note that it doesn't work as expected with `*` not at the beginning):

```
import re
common_name = "*.example.com"
# escaping the string to not contain any valid regex
common_name = re.escape(common_name)
# Replacing any occurences of the (regex-escaped) "*." with regex
regex = "^" + common_name.replace(r"\*\.", r"(\w*\.)?") + "$"
# yields the regex: ^(\w*\.)?example\.com$
url = "foo.bar.example.com"
if re.match(regex, url):
   print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

This matches your examples as expected

Comment: It raises an error:  raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Answer (score 3):

This regex will handle most cases:

```
r'([^\.]+\.)?example\.com'
```

Putting that into code:

```
import re

common_name = '*.example.com'
pattern = re.compile(common_name.replace('*.', r'([^\.]+\.)?', 1))

for domain in 'www.example.com', 'example.com', 'hello.example.com', 'foo.bar.example.com', '*.*.*', 'www.*.com':
    print('{}: {}'.format(domain, pattern.match(domain) is not None))
```

**Output**

```
www.example.com: True
example.com: True
hello.example.com: True
foo.bar.example.com: False
*.*.*: False
www.*.com: False
```

It's debatable whether `example.com` should be accepted, but the regex above will accept it.

Comment: mhawke, I got this from the logs:
Common Name: `*.example.com`
url: `example.com`

Comment: @philippe: if you need it then that's ok. You can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) as to whether you think you should accept the "naked" domain name.